# Why the following t-sql transaction does not work as expected?

Tags: sql-server, transactions

To test how a transaction work, I wrote the following t-sql. As the first attribute is the primary key, none of the insertions should be committed.
But, the first insertion is committed? Why?

```
begin transaction
   insert into instructor
   values ('99999', 'Yellow', 'Biology', 700000)

   insert into instructor
   values ('99999', 'Blue', 'Statistics', 85000)
commit;

select * from instructor where ID = '99999'

--delete from instructor where ID = '99999'
```

> (1 row affected) Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 100 Violation of
>   PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__instruct__3214EC278C8DA99F'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.instructor'. The duplicate key value is
>   (99999). The statement has been terminated.

Completion time: 2019-11-06T14:02:27.3436411+02:00

Comment: You can get this result if `XACT_ABORT` is `OFF`, because the duplicate key violation only aborts the second insert, and not the transaction as a whole, so the `COMMIT` still happens. If you do a `SET XACT_ABORT ON` first, the commit will not happen. The exact rules for what does and does not actually abort a transaction are [really complicated](http://sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html#classification), even if `XACT_ABORT` can simplify things considerably.

Answer (score 0):

Because, when the XACT_ABORT IS OFF (which is the default):

> When SET XACT_ABORT is OFF, in some cases only the Transact-SQL
>   statement that raised the error is rolled back and the transaction
>   continues processing.

and when it is `ON`:

> .. if a Transact-SQL statement raises a run-time error, the entire
>   transaction is terminated and rolled back.

That's what we need to turn it `ON` and if you try the code below, you can check this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[StackOverflow];

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StackOverflow]
(
    [StackID] TINYINT PRIMARY KEY
);

SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO [dbo].[StackOverflow] ([StackID])
VALUES (105);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[StackOverflow] ([StackID])
VALUES (105);

COMMIT TRANSACTION;

SET XACT_ABORT OFF;

SELECT [StackID]
FROM [dbo].[StackOverflow];
```

Also, note that:

> Compile errors, such as syntax errors, are not affected by SET XACT_ABORT.

The above means, that if you want to really have automatic transaction you need to use the following code block:

```
SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    -- CODE BLOCK GOES HERE
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH 

   IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
   BEGIN
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
   END;

   -- GET ERRORS DETAILS OR THROW ERROR

END CATCH;

SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT OFF;
```

If you do not use `TRY-CATCH` block in a specific situations, like the next one, the first statement will be again committed:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[StackOverflow];

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StackOverflow]
(
    [StackID] TINYINT PRIMARY KEY
);

SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO [dbo].[StackOverflow] ([StackID])
VALUES (105);

EXEC 
(
    'INSERrrrrrT INTO [dbo].[StackOverflow] ([StackID]) VALUES (106);'
)

COMMIT TRANSACTION;

SET XACT_ABORT OFF;

SELECT [StackID]
FROM [dbo].[StackOverflow];
```

Comment: Compile errors cannot be caught since they prevent the entire batch from running, including the `TRY` / `CATCH`, so wrapping a `BEGIN TRY` around the whole transaction has no added effect. The only way to `CATCH` such errors is to put the whole query in a dynamic `EXEC`, as the final example shows (which has its uses, but is not something you generally want to do; you're better off controlling the transaction from client code).

Comment: @JeroenMostert True, my point was that if you have for example dynamic T-SQL statement and you do something wrong there (for example forgot space and concatenate few clauses during the building) using XACT set to ON is not enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @gotqn!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` and/or use TRY/CATCH so that the script doesn't continue to the `COMMIT` after an error.

`SET XACT_ABORT ON` example:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
begin transaction
   insert into instructor
   values ('99999', 'Yellow', 'Biology', 700000)

   insert into instructor
   values ('99999', 'Blue', 'Statistics', 85000)
commit;
```

TRY/CATCH example:

```
BEGIN TRY
    begin transaction
       insert into instructor
       values ('99999', 'Yellow', 'Biology', 700000)
    
       insert into instructor
       values ('99999', 'Blue', 'Statistics', 85000)
    commit;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK;
    THROW;
END CATCH;
```

Although `SET XACT_ABORT ON` is optional with this TRY/CATCH pattern, I still recommend it in all T-SQL code with explict transactions. This will ensure the transaction is rolled back immediately even when batch is cancelled manually or due to a query timeout where no CATCH block code executes. Otherwise, the uncommitted transaction will remain open until the connection is closed or reused with connection pooling.

Comment: Please can you advise why you have mentioned "and/or use TRY/CATCH"? In the try/catch example you have not used xact_abort so is it optional when we use try/catch?

Comment: @variable, I added explanation to my answer.